# Display multiple files name VueJS error push is not a function

Tags: vue.js

I wan't to display multiple files name in my template i'm do that:

```
<div v-for="(image, index) in imagesReturn" :key="index">
          <span>{{ image.name }}</span>
        </div>
        <div>
          <generic-input
            v-model="imagesReturn"
            type="file"
            multiple
            @change="addFiles"
          >
            add files
          </generic-input>
       </div>

<script>
data() {
return{
 imagesReturn: [];
 }
}
methods: {
  addFiles(e) {
      let selectedFiles = e.target.files;
      for (let img of selectedFiles) {
        this.imagesReturn.push(img.name);
      }
    }
}
</script>
```

Iwant to display files name in array imagesReturn but i have error when i push inside array error ***this.imagesReturn.push is not a function*** i don't know why and i can not display files name in my template. Please thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The js part seems fine to me. I guess the problem goes from the `generic-input` component.

Typically, when the error `something.push is not a function` occurred, it always means `something` is not an Array.

Since `imagesReturn` is two-way binding using `v-model`, it is possible that the `generic-input` component alters `imagesReturn` from `[]` to `''`(empty string) or `null` after mounted.

So I suggest you `console.log(this.imagesReturn)` inside `addFiles()` to see when the value changes (or `watch` `imagesReturn`).

I don't know if the `generic-input` component belongs to a UI framework or is created by yourself. If belongs to a UI framework, you need to read the documentation carefully about `@change="function(params)"` event, especially its params. If it's wrote by yourself, you need to check what value it will pass in the component when `emit('change', value)`.

Comment: thank you @gengar.value is my component generic-input the problem i'm resolve that